# patch object or method fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-3.9, pytest-mock

I try to mock an async method which occurs within another async method, which I try to test.
I can patch the first mocked method, which only needs to return a primitive of the value `11000`. And it does.

But the complex object Order fails with the error message `TypeError: 'Order' object is not subscriptable`

```
from src.market_mgr import MarketMgr

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_unrealized_profit(mocker):
    # test setup fixture
    trade_mgr = TradeMgr()    
    trade0 = Trade(pos_idx=0, market="TSL/USD", price=1000)
    trade_mgr.save_trade(trade0)    
    
    # actual test    
    mocker.patch("market_mgr.MarketMgr.get_last_price", return_value=11000) # WORKS    
    patched_order = Order(market="TSLA/USD", price=10000) # TYPEERROR: 'Order' object is not subscriptable
    mocker.patch("order_mgr.OrderMgr.get_order", return_value=patched_order)    

    profit = await trade_mgr.get_unrealized_profit(0)
    assert profit == 10 #10% profit
```

I also tried to mock the object instead of the method:

```
mocker.patch.object(OrderMgr, "get_order", patched_order)
```

This returns the same error.

any hints on how to mock complex objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above was correct. I simply had to add the `__getitem__` method to the class I want to mock: class `OrderMgr`.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]
```

What does this do? It makes (in this case the mock engine) the bracket-notation available - in addition to the dot-notation.

dot-notation:

```
orderMgr.get_order
```

bracket-notation:

```
orderMgr['get_order']
```

Yes, this also counts for methods/functions. And you would get the same error if you would try to access an mocked attribute - IF - the `__getitem__` method is not available.

(I made the assumption that SQLModel/Pydantic would generate the **getitem**. That is not the case).